# Object/Module not found: RDS from VB6 app to a Win2003 server

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2003, rds

I have a rather legacy application EXE written in VB6 and running on a Windows 2000 server that uses RDS (Remote Data Services) to access a business object DLL (also written in VB6) running on a Windows 2003 server.  The DLL has never run on this server (we're moving the component off the old W2K server), but it is registered and defined as a component on the W2k+3 server.

The specific code where the DLL is being called is:

```
Private m_rdsDS As RDS.DataSpace
Dim oARImport As Object

Set oARImport = m_rdsDS.CreateObject("ARBatches.BL_ARBatches", txtWebServer)
MsgBox oARImport.AddBatches(m_vConnParms, arbParseString, LinesFromFile)
```

The CreateObject appears to work fine, but calling the method AddBatches raises the error number 8209 "Internet Server Error: Object/module not found."  I'm leaning towards the idea that there is a permission issue somewhere at the root of the problem, but if this were the case, why wouldn't it say "You don't have permission"?

I'd really like to rewrite the whole app but "they" won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a lot of debugging, but I finally solved the problem myself.  The "Object/Module not found" problem turned out to be a matter of MSADC not yet running on the server in a way that the ARBatches object could be found.